# Gradle Spring Boot Devtools: developmentOnly and runtimeClasspath

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin, spring-boot-devtools

I am puzzled by this block of code to be used in a `gradle` file, suggested by [Spring Boot Documentation on Developer Tools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-devtools)

```
configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}
dependencies {
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
}
```

I think I must declare the `developmentOnly` configuration because it is to be used in the `dependencies {}` block, but why do I need the lines for `runtimeClasspath`?  I actually tried removing the lines in my project and the project built prefectly fine.

```
configurations {
    developmentOnly
}
dependencies {
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
}
```

Is `runtimeClasspath` used by the Java Plugin? (As suggested by this [doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html))  Will there be any bad side-effect if I do not include those lines for `runtimeClasspath`?

**Update (2019-12-10)**

I can also confirm that the built executable jar built without the `runtimeClasspath` directive ran prefectly okay.  So I really don't know what that directive is doing.

Comment: You can read more about it in the original issue that sparked this change: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14451

Comment: @FranciscoMateo, Thanks for the pointer.  I have read the issue discussion but still don't quite understand it.  It seems `runtimeClasspath` is somehow used by someone, but I don't know how and who.  I have already re-read the documentation on the Java Plugin -- to no avail.  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html

Answer (score 6):

You need spring-boot-devtools only at runtime, that's why we're using runtimeClasspath config.

more details: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph

Answer (score 1):

- The `developmentOnly` is a new configuration that you add.
- The `runtimeClasspath` configuration is added by the `Java Library Plugin`.
- You specify that the `runtimeClasspath` configuration extend from your `developmentOnly` configuration.
- You set `spring-boot-devtools` as a dependency for your `developmentOnly` configuration, which will make the `runtimeClasspath` depend on `spring-boot-devtools` too.

> I actually tried removing the lines in my project and the project built prefectly fine.

I think this is because the dependency is for run time, not for build time.

> I can also confirm that the built executable jar built without the runtimeClasspath directive ran prefectly okay.

I think this is because `spring-boot-devtools` only works on development mode, e.g. when you execute the `bootRun` task with `./gradlew bootRun`.